# How to Hide window TitleBar using attached property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `MainWindow` I have to perform the `TitleBar` hide or visible in ViewModel using attached property. I have no idea how to make this. Please can anyone give me a suggestion or any workaround to achieve this. I am new to .Net

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleBarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TitleBarVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls.TitleBar));

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public bool TitleBarVisible
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MainWindow.TitleBarProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MainWindow.TitleBarProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("TitleBarVisible");
    }
}
```

[please refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCFCD.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, if so what? Thanks

Comment: I tried like this now, but not reflecting, i don't konw where i have done wrong, I edited my code please refer

Comment: Depends what you mean exactly, you could bind WindowStyle. None has no chrome on the top.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note that what you have is not an attached property, but a regular dependency property. There is no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for it, since dependency properties already come with their own change notification mechanism. In order to react on changes of the property value, register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property metadata. See [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties)

Comment: I have used ribbon window in mainwindow, i have to title bar visibility collapse or visible in viewmodel. In window is loaded event(code behind) i used like this(see below code), the title bar is hidden. but i have to change the visibilty again and again with respect to my requirement. I have attached the screenshot please refer.  MainWindow window = sender as MainWindow;
            window.TitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this without using attached peroperty like this,

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            MainWindow window = sender as MainWindow;
            window.TitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                        
        }
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public void HideTitleBar(object obj)
{
    (App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).TitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```